# RSpec: How to get example metadata before running suite

Tags: testing, rspec, tags, metadata

I'd like to get the metadata for the examples in my suite before running it. I want to parallelize my test suite based off of tags. Anyone know how to get this data during something like `RSpec.configure`?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a way to do this while running the suite. You could conceivably create a custom formatter and run the suite with `rspec --dry-run --format=MyFormatter`, capture the output, extract the metadata and then do what you want with it. Unfortunately it appears the built-in JSON formatter does not output example metadata.

More info on formatters in [the RSpec docs](http://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-3/docs/formatters/custom-formatters).

Comment: Agreed. I've made a custom formatter for this but it feels super wonky. Thanks for the `dry-run` reminder though. That will come in handy!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by inspecting,

```
RSpec.current_example.metadata
```

so for example, to detect if javascript is enabled:

```
def js_true?
  RSpec.current_example.metadata[:js]
end
```